# Transparent view while navigatiing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, presentmodalviewcontroller

While navigating from one view to other view, I want to make the second view transparent. i.e. After navigation first view contents should be visible.

I have tried by background color clear and Transparent background images.But on the time of navigation its transparent.

After full navigation the second view back ground becomes black .

Here my code,

```
 obj=[[loginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"loginViewController" bundle:nil];
 [self presentModalViewController:obj animated:YES];
```

Comment: its usual behavior...rather you can take a transparent view on first viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this only if you  **subview** the second view.

By using `presentmodalviewcontroller` or `pushviewcontroller` , your firstview will not be visible.

```
Secondview *second = [[Secondview alloc] initWithNibName:@"Secondview"  bundle:nil];
 [self.view addSubview:second.view];

    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromBottom];
    [[self.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transitionViewAnimation"];
```

Comment: then how can i give the animation from botton to up

Comment: I have made changes in the answer, now try . I forgot to add **second.view** when you addsubview this view.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to override drawRect: and take care of the alpha in it. You may not touch UIView's alpha property, nor may you set the view's background color to anything bat transparent. All drawing must be made in drawRect:. This way I was able to stack transparent views and pup opaque elements on top.